# How to split column from DataFrame with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

I am reading a CSV file from an API call into a data frame with pandas for some data manipulation.

Currently, I'm getting this response:

```
n [78]: dfname
Out[78]: 
        productID  amountInStock  index  index_col
7             1.0            NaN      1          7
19            4.0            NaN      2         19
20            1.0            NaN      3         20
22            2.0            NaN      4         22
```

I then call dfname.reset_index() to create a better index:

```
dfname.reset_index()
Out[80]: 
      level_0  productID  amountInStock  index  index_col
0           7        1.0            NaN      1          7
1          19        4.0            NaN      2         19
2          20        1.0            NaN      3         20
3          22        2.0            NaN      4         22
```

But the problem is that the 'productID' series has two columns and I can't work out how to split them!

```
dfname.productID
Out[82]: 
7          1.0
19         4.0
20         1.0
22         2.0
```

What I want is dfname.productID to return:

```
dfname.productID
Out[82]: 
7          
19         
20         
22
```

and the other figures currently in productID should be assigned to 'stockqty'.

How do I split this field so that it returns two columns instead of one?  I've tried .str.split() to no avail.

The properties of the object are Name: productID, Length: 2102, dtype: float64

Comment: why split? just rename them!

Comment: I tried renaming them but it just renamed the two columns. It seems that dataframe.productid contains before productid and stockqty so I need to figure how to split them. Maybe I need to look at the original CSV and add another separator ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the problem is that the 'productID' series has two columns and I
>   can't work out how to split them!

Therein lies the misunderstanding. You don't have 2 columns, despite what `print` tells you. You have one column with an **index**. This is precisely how a [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) object is defined.

> What I want is dfname.productID to return:

As above, this isn't possible. Every series has an index. This is non-negotiable.

> How do I split this field so that it returns two columns instead of
>   one? I've tried .str.split() to no avail.

This isn't the way forward. In particular, note [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) is for *splitting strings* within series. You don't have strings here. Instead, use `reset_index` and rename your column. Or name your index before `reset_index`. The latter option seems cleaner to me:

```
df.index.name = 'stockqty'
df = df.reset_index()

print(df)

   stockqty  productID  amountInStock  index  index_col
0         7        1.0            NaN      1          7
1        19        4.0            NaN      2         19
2        20        1.0            NaN      3         20
3        22        2.0            NaN      4         22
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense - thank you. I'll give that a bash later and hopefully it'll give me the desired result

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by specifying the separator when parsing the csv:

```
        df = pd.read_csv(link, encoding='ISO-8859-1', sep=', ', engine='python')
```